# Can't create recurring event in django-scheduler

Tags: django, rrule, django-scheduler

I would like to specify an event which results in occurences between hours 16-21, everyday.

How can I accomplish this?

I have already tried a lot to do this, e.g. by specifing Event.start to 16:00 and Event.end to 21:00 with "daily" frequency rule, but no luck. Only occurrences between 15:30 and 16 show up.

[image]

the _get_occurrence_list on Event model get's called with half hour intervals.

I already doubt it's possible. Does django-scheduler support such a use case?

Comment: what scheduler are you using.? And secondly, are you sure you are not using two different **timezones** , one being **UTC** (maybe in some settings) and one being of the place you are.?

Comment: django-scheduler I use: https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler This is my time zone setting: TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw', and same is set on my Linux. Anyway, if it would be a problem with timezone i assume that it should show occurences through 5 hours as defined in event, just with some offset (a bit up or down on the calendar). But it just shows 2 occurences instead 10...

Answer (score 0):

Create an event with an HOURLY rule.
Then give it these parameter: "byhour:16,17,18,19,20;"

In the database, you should see the following:

- schedule_event:

  - start = start date, 16h
  - end = start date, 17h       (indeed, **START** date here)
  - rule_id = X  (Any number, but same as below X)
- schedule_rule:

  - id = X
  - frequency = HOURLY
  - params: byhour:16,17,18,19,20;

Reference:
http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57